# Data Cleaning Consequence on a Pre-Built Index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

**Objective:**

To create an Index that accommodates a pre-existing set of price data from a csv file.  I can build an index using list comprehensions. If it's done in that way, the construction would give me a filtered list of length 86,772--when run over 1/3/2007-8/30/2012 for 42 times (i.e. 10 minute intervals). However, my data of prices coming from the csv is length: 62,034. Observe that the difference in length is due to ***data cleaning issues***.

That said, I am not sure how to overcome the apparent mismatch between the *real* data and this pre-built (list comp) dataframe.

**Attempt:**

Am I using the first two lines incorrectly?

```
data=pd.read_csv('___.csv', parse_dates={'datetime':[0,1]}).set_index('datetime')

dt_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.combine(i.date,i.time) for i in data.index])

ts = pd.Series(data.prices.values, dt_index)
```

**Questions:**

1. As I understand it, I should use 'combine' since ***I want the index construction to be completely informed by my csv file***. And, 'combine' returns a new datetime object whose date components are equal to the given date object’s, and whose time components are equal to the given time object’s.
2. When I parse_dates, is it lumping the time and date together and considering it to be a 'date'?
3. Is there a better way to achieve the stated objective?

**Traceback Error:**

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: I've added an example in my answer but I think it might be useful to add the first few lines of your dataset (e.g. output of `data[:3]`). Is it possible that your dates or times are malformed and haven't converted properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this neatly as follows:

```
ts = df1.prices
```

Here's an example:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('prices.csv',
                  parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1]}).set_index('datetime')

In [2]: df # dataframe
Out[2]: 
                    prices  duty
datetime                 
2012-11-12 10:00:00      1     0
2012-12-12 10:00:00      2     0
2012-12-12 10:00:00      3     1


In [3]: df.prices # timeseries
Out[3]: 
datetime
2012-11-12 10:00:00    1
2012-12-12 10:00:00    2
2012-12-12 11:00:00    3
Name: prices

In [4]: ts = df.prices
```

You can groupby date like so (similar to [this example from the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation)):

```
In [5]: key = lambda x: x.date()

In [6]: df.groupby(key).sum()
Out[6]: 
            prices  duty
2012-11-12       1     0
2012-12-12       5     1

In [7]: ts.groupby(key).sum()
Out[7]: 
2012-11-12    1
2012-12-12    5
```

Where **prices.csv** contains:

```
date,time,prices,duty
11/12/2012,10:00,1,0
12/12/2012,10:00,2,0
12/12/2012,11:00,3,1
```

Comment: the index is not parsed as Timestamp. look at the error message: it is unicode. so ts will be no time series.

Comment: you are right, however the traceback of the OP suggests that this is a unicode string. maybe he uses a different pandas version.

Comment: maybe. however I'll upvote your answer because I was not aware that I do not need the `index_col` in this case.

Comment: @hayden 

The error is coming from the second line above there (ie datatimeindex). It's not an issue with the dataset; as it has date as its zeroth column and time as its 1st column. The Pandas version is 0.9.1.

Comment: @hayden Yes.

Though I am thinking that it might still be desirable to have the data transformed into a Series (as above) to take advantage of the time series optimization tools. Still curious whether there is a good way to do that.

Also, would you agree then, using your suggestion, if we want to apply a function/algorithm restricted  every unique date in the file one should just groupby the 'datetime' object?

Comment: @user1374969 `ts` is a timeseries, I've updated with how to groupby date, hope this helps.